# S3 TopicConfiguration- Unable to validate the following destination configurations

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I'm trying to get an S3 event notification to trigger multiple Lambda functions in parallel.

Need to go via SNS as you can't define multiple S3 `LambdaConfigurations` which have the same S3 `Prefix` - Cloudformation complains of "overlap" :-(

So I am following this pattern here -

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/fanout-s3-event-notifications-to-multiple-endpoints/

however I keep falling foul of `Unable to validate the following destination configurations` when deploying. This *seems* to be related to a missing `SNS::TopicPolicy`, as well documented here -

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-destination-s3/

however I have a `TopicPolicy` defined (see below), and have made the `Bucket` creation dependent on it. What am I doing wrong here ? TIA.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  AppName:
    Type: String
Resources:
  Topic:
    Properties:
      TopicName: !Sub "${AppName}-topic"
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
  TopicPolicy:
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Id: !Sub "${AppName}-topic-policy"
        Statement:
          - Action: "sns:Publish"
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: 's3.amazonaws.com'
            Resource: Ref! Topic
            Sid: !Sub "${AppName}-topic-policy-statement"
        Version: '2012-10-17'
      Topics:
        - !Ref Topic
    Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
  Bucket:
    DependsOn:
      - TopicPolicy
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub "${AppName}-bucket"
      NotificationConfiguration:
        TopicConfigurations:
          - Event: "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
            Topic: !Ref Topic
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
```

Comment: This might sound really silly but could you try reordering your template so that it's as in the example from the link, i.e. first topic, then topic policy, then bucket? I know the dependencies should work but there've been a few occasions in the past where putting them in desired creation order has helped.

Comment: nice try, but still getting the same error! lol

Answer (score 0):

Bad reference to `Resource: Ref! Topic` when it should have been `Resource: !Ref Topic` :( :( :(

Passes template validation though! Lol.

Moral is to do more template sanity checking prior to deployment :-/